# Angular2 upgradeAdapter not working with $rootScope, $state etc

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, upgrade

Im trying to upgrade an Angular1 application with the help of Angular2's upgradeAdapter. The app is bootstrapped with the upgradeAdapter and works as expected, at least as long as I don't try to upgrade one of A1's integrated services.

Let's say i have this A1 Service written in typescript:

```
//A1.ts
// inject decorator that in short does target.$inject = ...injects
@Inject('$rootScope')
class TestService{
    constructor($rootScope: angular.IRootScopeService){
        //$rootScope.whatever();
    }
} 
// register the service in application module
globalModule.service('TestService', TestService);
```

I can inject the TestService the normal A1 way wherever I need to, and it works.

Now for the A2 upgrade i do:

```
//upgradeAdapter.ts
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
export default upgradeAdapter;

//A2.ts
import upgradeAdapter from './upgradeAdapter'
import { Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core'

@Injectable()
export class A2TestService{
    constructor(@Inject('$rootScope') _rootScope: angular.IRootScope){
        //_rootScope.whatever()
    }
}

upgradeAdapter.upgradeNG1Provider('$rootScope');
// tried with additional upgradeAdapter.upgradeNG1Provider('$rootScopeProvider');
upgradeAdapter.addProvider(A2TestService);
// make this service available in A1 World
globalModule.service('A2TestService',upgradeAdapter.downgradeNG2Provider(A2TestService));
```

Hybrid DI works when upgrading with this formula, as long as I don't use, e.g., `$rootScope` like above.
Then I am getting

```
"Error during instantiation of $rootScope!  (A2TestService -> $rootScope)
Stacktrace: Type Error: Cannot read property 'get' of null 
 at provider.push.core_1.provide.useFactory (upgrade.js: 684)
..."
```

coming from angular2.js (on beta.9)

What are my options here?